# Spring Boot with Groovy and External Libraries

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot

I'm working on building what is effectively a throwaway Spring Boot application.  Using the CLI, I can get a basic page up and working (see https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).  What I haven't figured out how to do, however, is how I can add external dependencies (ie. third-party JAR files) to the compile or runtime classpath when I use either the "spring run" or "spring jar" commands.  Note that these external dependencies are local to my computer and are not stored in an artifact repository.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the jars aren't in an artifact repository, the easiest way to add them to the classpath is to use `-cp` when running your app or creating its jar.

For example:

```
spring run -cp foo.jar app.groovy
```

Or:

```
spring jar -cp foo.jar app.jar app.groovy
```

In the `spring jar` case, anything that's added to the classpath using `-cp` will be packaged inside the resulting jar (app.jar in this case) ensuring that it's self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

you can use groovy's [`@Grab`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape) notation (there is also `spring grab` call).  E.g.

```
@Grab('joda-time:joda-time:2.5')

@RestController
class ThisWillActuallyRun {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return new org.joda.time.DateTime().toString()
    }

}
```